# DrawRectangle() does not draw on topmost Layer of elements

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a `wxFrame` with several `wxTextCtrl` and other members of a custom *Image Class* which is derived from `wxWindow` and has a `wxImage` member.

In the `wxFrame`'s `OnPaint` *event function* I draw a rectangle that is supposed to be located on top of the bitmaps but keeps getting painted on the bottommost layer behind the `wxTextCtrls` and `wxBitmaps`.

This is my `OnPaint()`:

```
void MyPanel::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& /*event*/)
{
        wxPaintDC paintDC(this);
        paintDC.SetBrush(wxBrush(wxColour(90, 156, 214, 255)));
        paintDC.SetPen(wxPen(wxColour(90, 156, 214, 255)));
        wxRect oRect(10,10,800,900);
        paintDC.DrawRectangle(oRect);
}
```

I call the `OnPaint` with a `Refresh()` from within the `MyPanel`

Answer (score 0):

In these cases the most probable cause is the order of which the drawn objects are attached to the window, i.e. you could call the `DrawRectangle()` function after the functions of the rest of the drawn objects, but if you attach the result of `DrawRectangle()` before the others, it remains on the bottom.

Comment: But when are the other object's OnPaint fuctions called? In the Panel's OnPaint I really only draw the rectangle.

Comment: I see, in that case, the other reason I could think of is the argumenty of  `paintDC()`, i.e. is `this` a pointer to the place you want the rectangle to be drawn on?

Comment: Well  'this' is a pointer to my MyPanel object, of which all the wxTextCtrls and Images are members. So this is where I want to draw on actually. Above all the other members.

Comment: Could you please try just `DrawRectangle(oRect);`, without prefixing `paintDC.`

Comment: `DrawRectangle()` is not a member of MyPanel (which is of `wxPanel`)

Comment: I can see though that the `OnPaint` of my custom image class is called after the `OnPaint` of `MyPanel` (in wich the rectangle is drawn) I have no idea why though.

Comment: @tzippy This explains why everything is redrawn on top of the rectangle, I guess :)

Comment: Yes :) But how can I have the OnPaint of my panel be called at last. Or how do I know what calls the OnPaint of the image?

Comment: @tzippy That is a different question that should be asked as a new. We discovered why the rectangle is not on the top, which [IMO] should complete this post. You could formulate something like: "Function call order in my class?" or something similar

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a question but, yes, to confirm what you wrote: no, you can't paint on top of the other controls, it simply doesn't work like this. I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but you will need to find another approach.